# How to convert unix_timestamp interger in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unix-timestamp, postgresql-8.0

How to convert a unix_timestamp integer to time in readable text.
Such as:

```
timestamp|integer|not null default 0
```

```
select timestamp from table limit 1; 
1541001600
```

1541001600 should be converted to `Thu Nov 1 00:00:00 CST 2018`

PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 8.0? That has been unsupported for ages. What does `select version();` show you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_timestamp()` in postgresql.

```
select to_timestamp(1541001600) AT TIME ZONE 'CST';
```

Refer [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61325/how-to-convert-a-unix-time-to-postgresql-timstamp-without-timezome/61345#61345) for more details

For 8.0:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1541001600 * INTERVAL '1 second';
```

Comment: It does not work.  The error information is as follows    

ERROR:  function to_timestamp(integer) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Documentation says function accepts double type, maybe try `to_timestamp(1541001600.0)`?

Comment: For 8.0, the to_timestamp(double precision) itself is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

You should really upgrade your Postgres!  But I think this will work:

```
select '1970-01-01'::timestamp + 1541001600 * interval '1 second'
```